# How do I upload an image of custom dimensions in React Native, using the expo-image-picker library?

Tags: react-native, expo

Below is the code I have already that requires you to crop whatever image you select from the camera roll to a square. I would like to use different dimensions.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

export default function ImagePickerExample() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can follow this way**

In expo image picker library  you can change your aspect (aspect ratio) to change the. Dimensions of the image after selection.

What you need to do is remove aspect from your pickImage() function then you will be able to crop in any dimension.

Here you have given aspect : [4,3] so that is the dimension of image, you can remove it.